# how to I ignore the /* */ comment section?

Tags: java

I am writing a program that checks whether these { [ ( " and /* symbols are balanced with } ] ) " */. What is troubling me right now is that my logic for handling the comment /* */ section doesn't seem to be working. How do I make this program ignore whatever is in the `/* */` (a block of comments)? **I have tried the indexOf(/***) method and it doesn't work for me so please don't call this a duplicate.  Specifically, is there a way to handle this using boolean?

Here is my **comment logic** :

```
if(ch == '{'||ch =='(' || ch=='['){    
                            if(notinComment == true){
                                ms.push(ch);
                                notinComment = false;
                            }
                            notinComment = true;
                        }
```

And here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SymbolBalance {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        if(args.length>0){
            try{
                Scanner input = new Scanner(new File (args[0]));
                MyStack<Character> ms = new MyStack<>();
                boolean quoteStart = true;
                boolean notinComment = true;
                char ch;

                loop: while(input.hasNext()){
                String str = input.next();
                    for(int i=0; i<str.length();i++){
                        ch = str.charAt(i);
                        //ignore the comment logic 
                        if(ch == '{'||ch =='(' || ch=='['){    
                            if(notinComment == true){
                                ms.push(ch);
                                notinComment = false;
                            }
                            notinComment = true;
                        }
                        else if(ch == '/' && i<str.length()-1 && str.charAt(i+1) == '*'){
                            ms.push(str.charAt(i+1));
                        }

                        else if (ch==')'){
                            if(ms.isEmpty()||ms.pop()!= '('){
                               System.out.println(") is mismatched");
                               break loop;
                            }
                        }
                       else if(ch == ']'){
                            if(ms.isEmpty() || ms.pop() != '['){
                                System.out.println("] is mismatched");
                                break loop;
                            }      
                       }
                        else if(ch == '}'){
                            if(ms.isEmpty() || ms.pop() != '{'){
                                System.out.println("} is mismatched");
                                break loop;
                            }
                        }
                        else if(ch == '*' && i<str.length() -1 && str.charAt(i+1) == '/'){
                            if(ms.isEmpty() || ms.pop() != '*'){
                                System.out.println("*/ is mismatched");
                                break loop;
                            }   
                        }
                       else if(ch == '"'){
                            if(quoteStart == true) {
                                ms.push(ch);
                                quoteStart = false;
                            }
                            else {
                                if(ms.isEmpty() || ms.pop() != '"'){
                                    System.out.println(" \" is mismatched");  
                                    break loop;
                                }
                                quoteStart = true;
                            }
                        } //end of else 
                    }//end fof while
                }//end of while 
                input.close();
            }//end of try
            catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                   System.out.println("Cannot find file");
           }//end of catch
        }//end of if
        else{
               System.out.println("No command line argument");
        }
    }

}
```

and here goes an example input file that we need to examine:

```
/* this is to test whether the program can deal with an imbalance of { */
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean haveYouWatchedHamiltonYet = true;
        int theSchuylerSisters = 3; 
        int alexanderhamilton = 1;
        int aaronburr = 1;

        boolean amIinTheRoom = theRoomWhereItHappens();
        /* imbalanced { test */
        {

    }

    /*just a general comment */ 
    public boolean theRoomWhereItHappens() {
        boolean intheRoomWhereItHappens = false;
        boolean isHappyAboutThis = false;
        return intheRoomWhereItHappens && isHappyAboutThis;

    }
}
```

Comment: i think its better to user Regular Expression for this kind of task.

Comment: what do you mean by Regular Expression?

Comment: in short they call it regex, look at `java.util.regex.Matcher` and `java.util.regex.Pattern`

Comment: I don't think we are allowed to use it in this hw

Comment: As Yunus stated, regex will save you more line codes and makes your fingers happy. Read here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Comment: And, you should provide some examples (input, output), then we may help

Comment: thx! I did provide input